# What is this small plant with broad leaves and 5 petal purple flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

In Chicago. The flower and leaves look different from periwinkle. Also the color seems to be a deeper purple. It spreads quickly and the plants only grow up to a few inches high. It blooms in April.

Roots seem to be short, and each plant appears to have a few leaves and 1-2 flowers at most (so the picture actually shows multiple plants bunched next to each other)

Related questions did not look the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Violets, there may also be some white ones around. Here in zone 8 they are invasive except the deer like them and keep the violets under control. If you are looking for purple early blooming ,hardy plants ,look at ajuga.

Comment: Haha I kept searching “purple flower” but never tried “violet flower”. Thanks, too bad they’re invasive

Comment: I would call only some violet species invasive. There are some white violets that are very nasty, and Wood Violets (a native wildflower) are my state's State Wildflower but are difficult to remove in a lawn once they've colonized it. They're best left to wooded areas. OTOH, there are "red" violets. speckled violets (first found near Baraboo, Wisconsin), yellow violets (Viola pubescens) and species like Viola corsica which are not invasive, probably due to poor germination of seeds.They're all happily in my garden. Ajuga is actually incredibly invasive and impossible to eradicate from a lawn.

Comment: Yes, ajuga may cross the thin line between "very easy to grow" and "invasive." . My yard does tend to lean toward "invasive " plants.